# passing arrays (&) to functions c++, runtime error

Tags: c++, arrays, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void input(int(&x)[10]);
int copy(int (&x)[10], int(&y)[10]);
void read(int(&x)[10], int b);


int main()
{
    int m[10], v[10], c; 
    input((&m)[10]);
    read((&m)[10], 10);
    c = copy((&m)[10], (&v)[10]);
    read((&v)[c],c);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

void input(int(&x)[10])
{
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter number "<<i+1<<": ";
        cin>>x[i];
    }
}

void read(int(&x)[10], int b)
{
    for(int i=0; i < b; i++)
    {
        cout<<"number("<<i+1<<"): "<<x[i];
    }
}

int copy(int(&x)[10], int(&y)[10])
{
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(x[i] % 3 == 0)
        {
            y[c]=x[i];
            c++;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

I get a runtime error when i input the first number, any help will be appreciated 
I think the problem is in the way i pass the arrays to the functions but I am not really sure
the aim of the program is to get input for 10 int-s in the array m, than transfer those divisible by 3 to v, and output both

Comment: @skk: Irrelevant in this case, because the program could cause _anything_ to happen, including opening a micro black hole in your eyeball.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of passing an array is **not correct** (though it compiles). It should be as simple as,

```
input(m);
read(m, 10);
c = copy(m, v);
read(v, c);
```

`int(&x)[10]` should be used for the function prototype where you are receiving an array of size 10 by reference. While calling the function simply pass the name of the variable.

Comment: However, it's interesting that OP's code compiles, if kept as it is. I never knew that.

Comment: @iammilind: `(&m)[10]` is the tenth element of an array of arrays, and so has the correct type for the function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, yes I saw your answer. But then what is the difference between `m[10]` and `(&m)[10]`, if both are 10th element. Does the later syntax creates a reference ? Can we create reference like that ?

Comment: @iammilind: It is _not_ the case that both are the 10th element of `m`. Read Mike's answer again! `&m` is an `int(*)[10]` which, as far as this type knows, points to one or more arrays of 10 `int`s each. The OP has only one but with `(&m)[10]` he's trying to pass a reference to the mythical 10th such array of 10 `int`s. That's why it compiles; `m[10]` would not as the function does not accept an `int`.

Comment: @iammilind: `m[10]` is the tenth of an array of integers, an lvalue of type `int`. `(&m)[10]` is the tenth of an array of ten-element arrays, an lvalue of type `int[10]` (which can therefore be bound to a reference to `int[10]`). Its address is the same as `m[100]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
input((&m)[10]);
```

This doesn't do what you think it does; `&m` is a pointer to an array, so `(&m)[10]` is a reference to the 10th element of an array of arrays; in other words, to an invalid block of memory some distance off the end of `m`.

You want `input(m);` to pass a reference to `m`.

Answer (score 0):

> void input(int(&x)[10])

In this function signature:

- `x` is the argument name
- `int(&)[10]` is the argument type (reference to an array of 10 `int`s).

Now consider how you've called this function, presumably by copy/paste:

> ```
> input((&m)[10]);
> ```

With any function call, you write just the name of a variable, not its type; so, when you're passing the array to the function, you should just write:

```
input(m);
```

<sup>(At present you're passing something else that does not exist in memory, because of `&`'s triple meaning.)</sup>

Same goes for the other places where you pass [references to] arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing pointers to the functions, not references.

```
input((&m)[10]);
```

In the line above, the `&` is getting the address of `m`, and making it into a pointer.
The functions are not expecting pointers. Skip the `&` in the calls, and it should work.

Also, I suggest you try to find a tutorial describing the difference between a pointer and a reference. A quick Google search turned up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57483/440558) question here on Stack Overflow, with some good answers.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work to pass arrays into c++. This will result in a run time error unless you use pointers or create a class that contains an array and pass that.

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on the answer above: m[10] is past the last element in the array so what happens is you are reading memory outside your variables which is generally considered to be bad form.

Comment: The OP did not write `m[10]`.